# using clipto() with canvas setzoom(x) in fabric.js

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

We are using `setZoom(x)` for canvas zoom in and zoom out, and using `clipto()` on it but its not respective to canvas zoom level. any workaround for achieving desired result???

Comment: Can you share some code samples? a fiddle would be better.